# Cannot install xml2json module using npm in Windows 10

Tags: npm

I am trying to install xml2json using npm , but the console returns the following error

I run `npm i xml2json`

Then , the console returns this error

```
C:\Users\VDSCH\Proyectos\Tossa\problemApp\node_modules\node-expat>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\VDSCH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\VDSCH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\VDSCH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32"", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\VDSCH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\VDSCH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\VDSCH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\VDSCH\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\VDSCH\Proyectos\Tossa\problemApp\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN problemapp@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN problemapp@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.18 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.18 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\VDSCH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-26T16_59_24_765Z-debug.log
```

In the end i have tried reinstalling node-gyp and node expat but those dont seem to work. Is there something wrong with the package or am i missing something from my own system variables?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue on Linux, although the installation goes successful after many GCC warnings from `node-gyp` and some deprecation warnings from NPM.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself says something about not finding the `python` executable, and asking you to set the `PYTHON` environment variable to locate it.

So, the first question is, do you have python installed?  If not, you should [install it](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Then, before you run the process again, set the `PYTHON` environment variable to locate it.

Comment: i have python installed , do i need to set the enviroment variable to the executable?

Comment: It returns the same error as before when setting the python enviroment variable

Comment: Is your environment variable set all the way to your `python.exe` (or `python3.exe` or whatever), or just to the directory?  It looks like the variable should be all the way to the `.exe`.